# Button transparent on preview but solid on emulator

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set some buttons as transparent, well partially transparent. They're using a transparent/solid color gradient.

They show up just fine on the preview but on the emulator and on my phone it loses all transparency.

[Preview](https://www.screencast.com/t/yes89AZPj6)

[Emulator](https://www.screencast.com/t/Qtt0bzigZD)

Here's my XML code:

```
<Button
                    android:id="@+id/barbarian"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
                    android:text="@string/barbarian" />
```

xml gradient code if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="#FF000000"
    android:angle="0" />
   </shape>
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: maybe you have a different button_gradient.xml for other devices/screens?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not that experienced with android yet. I don't know what that means. How would I check this?

Comment: You can provide different files for different screen resolution (on different devices) look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support